# Using reference to head node while reversing linked list using recursion

Tags: java, linked-list, comparative-review

Referring to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466192/reversing-the-linkedlist-using-recursion-generating-wrong-output/33466315#33466315), should I consider using `current` pointers for this code snippet for reversing a linked list using recursion?

```
public static List ReverseRecursion(List head){

        List newHead;
        List current = head;

        if(current == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(current.next == null){
            head = current;
            return head;
        }
        newHead = ReverseRecursion(current.next);
        current.next.next = current;
        current.next = null;
        return newHead;

    }
```

Or should I consider the solution without using `current` node as someone pointed out in their solution like this?

```
public static List ReverseRecursion(List head){
    List newHead;

    if(head == null){
        return null;
    }
    if(head.next == null){
        return head;
    }

    newHead = ReverseRecursion(head.next);
    head.next.next = head;
    head.next = null;
    return newHead;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Extra variable unnecessary

Your variable `current` in the first code snippet is assigned to `head` and never changes, so it is unnecessary.  You can just use `head` directly instead, as in the second code snippet.  Therefore I feel the second version is superior.

## Iterative version

Consider using an iterative version to reverse the list instead of a recursive version.  An iterative solution uses \$O(1)\$ space instead of \$O(n)\$ space, and is much easier to understand as well.  All you need to do is take each element of the list and add it to the head of a new list, like this:

```
public static List ReverseList(List head)
{
    List newHead = null;

    while (head != null) {
        List next = head.next;

        head.next = newHead;
        newHead   = head;
        head      = next;
    }
    return newHead;
}
```